# Register spring bean with generic argument programmatically

Tags: java, spring, generics

Let's assume that I have some Abstract generic class:

```
public abstract class AbstractExampleService<T extends Foo> {
    // some logic around T
}
```

Besides I have x implementations of that class like:

```
@Component
public class FirstExampleService extends AbstractExampleService<FirstExample>{
}
```

So far so good

But as you can see, there is no logic in the implemented class, so I would like to write some infrastructure code instead this implementation.

I would like to register x implementation on application startup:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Autowired
    private List<Foo> fooList;

    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    public void initServiceBeans(){
        for (Foo foo : fooList) {
            Class<? extends Foo> aClass = foo.getClass();
            registerGenericService(AbstractExampleService.class, aClass, aClass.getSimpleName() + "Service");

        }
    }

    private void registerGenericService(Class<?> parentClass, Class<? extends Foo> genericArgument, String beanName){
        // How to implement it????
    }
}
```

How to implement this logic?